# How to get the most recent record using TSQL?

Tags: t-sql

```
Table a
ID Name
1  aa
2  bb
3  cc

Table b
ID Name  DateTime     aID
1  a1    2010-10-10   1
2  b1    2010-11-10   1
3  c1    2011-01-01   1
4  d1    2010-09-09   2
4  e1    2010-09-09   2


SELECT a.Name, b.Name
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN Table b ON (a.ID = b.aID, b.status = 1)
```

In result of this above query, I need only those record where max(datetime) in table b. 
Result:-

> aa, c1

**Note: In my real query, i have many many joins and where conditions. Group by won't work here.**

Comment: Should there ALWAYS be only one row in the result?  Or am I overcomplicating this trying to get the max for each row from A?

Comment: Tevo D. There are more than one row...

Comment: So give the sample data, should there be a second row in the result for aID=2?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE b.DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM b)
```

Comment: In my real query, I have more than 7 joins and 10 where conditions... Is there any other way other than WHERE clause? Thanks

Comment: `WHERE` is the proper place for reducing your result. You could add the same constraint with an `AND` in your `ON` clause, but since you're doing a left join, this would not necessarily reduce the list, but rather leave you with a lot of unmatched fields, where the `b`-values would be `null`.

Comment: In any case (whether WHERE Condition or with AND in ON clause), its returning null. and there is no null value in table b

Comment: Hmm, something else must be wrong. `b.DateTime` will be null if it's left joined against a field in `a` table that it doesn't match; it has nothing to do with whether or not there are null values in the actual table. Adding the condition at the `ON` level will definitely give you this result. Clearly, if you're saying `WHERE b.DateTime = (select a date time here)` then no null values will ever match that criteria. This is probably related to the other 10 hwere conditions you've mentioned, perhaps an `OR` that cancels out a lot of other constraints.

Comment: David. This above where clause gives Invalid Object name 'b' error

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that uses a ranking function to identify the "biggest" date, then filters down the query.  Caution: It may not perform very well under certain circumstances.

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Name
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN (
  select aID, DateTime, rank() over (order by b.DateTime desc) as rownum
  from TableB
) b ON a.ID = b.aID and b.status = 1
where
b.rownum = 1 -- first row
```